# I know how to do X in language Y, but not in language W

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Using the title of this question as a template, where is the right place to ask a question like:

---

## `<BEGIN OF EXAMPLE>`

### Transform and Multiply a String `n`-times

I can do this in Ruby:

```
print "hello".upcase * n
```

How can I upcase and write the result string `n` times in *language W*?

## `<END OF EXAMPLE>`

---

I have [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in mind, but I am not sure.

Comment: Perhaps it's because you explicitly say in the answer comments you already know about [so] but are unwilling to get your question up to its standards. Stack Overflow is not a code transcription service, nor there is any, nor are people willing to maintain one (maybe if you offered some money for that - but don't advertise your job position here...)

Comment: "nor are people willing to maintain one". My understanding is perfectly fine. You can poke Area51, but I don't think anyone will be willing to contribute - and if they do, they will soon give up once they run out of steam (even if the site managed to take off, which it won't).

Comment: "Maybe writing the code and using the already established Code Review would work out better." - that's a good call (as long as by "write the code" you mean "in W". It might even be helpful to include the respective Y code for comparison. Do not expect bug fixing / bug hunting from them, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, this question is two questions:

1. How to capitalize strings in W?
2. How to repeat a string n times in W?

Second, is Y relevant to the question? Not directly. It is helpful to show: *I have in mind the equivalent of this Ruby code*, since it removes doubts about what do you mean. But that's all.

After this, it is a standard programming question that belongs to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: "belongs to Stack Overflow." - and almost definitely was answered already - and also by the documentation for W. Just sayin'

Comment: @JanDvorak I expect that the trivial question above is just a trivial example, and that the true question would be less trivial.

Comment: @JorgeBucaran I disagree strongly. It is **your business** to prepare the question in such a way that it's reasonable. **You** want something, not the people willing to **help** you.

Comment: @JorgeBucaran http://area51.stackexchange.com/ <-- good luck.